# Can't find the deployed application in List Applications in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, sesame

I have deployed two war files for Java Sesame: `openrdf-sesame.war` and `openrdf-workbench.war` and found them on the List Applications in the `Tomcat Web Application Manager`. When I restarted the `Tomcat 6` on `Terminal`, I could not find them on the `List Applications`. I tried to deploy them again, it shows me the following message:

```
FAIL - War file "openrdf-sesame.war" already exists on server
```

When I go to the `apache-tomcat-6.0.37`, I find them under the folder `webapps` but can’t find them in the `List Applications`. Could anyone please guide what I should do at this point? Why can I not find these two folders on the List Applications anymore and how can I get them back?

Comment: It sounds like Tomcat failed to deploy the two webapps on restart. Have a look in the Tomcat logs to see if there are any hints on what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I removed and reinstalled `apache-tomcat-6.0.37` and deployed the `war files` needed. I started `tomcat` and found the `sesame` applications in the `Applications lists` in the `Tomcat Manager`.